# stringstream sometimes won't reach the end of a file

Tags: c++, eof, stringstream

I wrote a c++ program to manupilate data files. However in 5 files out of 100, the stringstream can't reach the end of the file. I ran tests within the following chunk of code:

```
// ssFile contains the whole text in each file.
// chunk is a string.
// value is an int
// tId and tName are both string vectors.
loop = 0;
while(ssFile >> chunk)
{ 
        if(ssFile.eof()) cout << "\nEOF!\n" << endl;

    if( chunk == "<frame>" )
    {
        if( ! (ssFile >> value ) )
                      cout << "ssFile>>value failed" << endl;

        cout << "-> " << loop << ": " << chunk << value;
        {
            stringstream ssVal;
            if( ! (ssVal << value ))
                             cout << "ssVal<<value failed" << endl;
            tId.push_back(ssVal.str());
        }
        loop++;
        if( ! (ssFile >> chunk ))
                     cout << "ssFile>>chunk2 failed" << endl;

        tName.push_back(chunk);
        cout << "= " << chunk << endl;
    } 
}// while (ssFile >> chunk)
```

In these 5 particular files, the ssFile sstream reaches no end at all: the loop is endlessly executed. I checked these txt files but their end doesn't seem to be different from the others.
Does it come from the stringstreams (which I doubt)? Or more probably from these files? If so how are end of files characters represented, perhaps these file are missing one?

Edit: added an EOF test and the following output:

```
-> 1: <frame>1= flying
-> 2: <frame>2= flying
-> 3: <frame>3= flying
-> 4: <frame>4= flying
-> 5: <frame>5= flying
-> 6: <frame>10= hiting
-> 7: <frame>11= hiting
-> 8: <frame>12= hiting
-> 9: <frame>13= hiting
-> 10: <frame>20= hit
-> 11: <frame>21= hit
-> 12: <frame>22= hit
-> 13: <frame>23= hit
-> 14: <frame>30= rebounding
-> 15: <frame>31= rebounding
-> 16: <frame>32= rebounding
-> 17: <frame>33= rebounding

EOF!

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Actually the loop is not executed again, the program just happens to be stuck at the last occurence... So there is no infinite loop/output. THe end of file seems to be detected, but still the program does not get out of the loop. Then it tells me a bad allocation has been made.

Last edit:

After endless debugging hours, I located the error which had nothing related to the loop. Basically, once the file has been read once, I clear the sstream and put the file containt into again, so it's like re-opening the file.
Then I use sstream >> char, reading every char one by one. I am first locating the next non-white-space char in a loop. Once done, I'm looping again to get the end of the word. Then, since i'm interesting in the value that comes next, I do the same loops, and here lied my error: I assumed something was following the first patterns, wihtout checking the sstream.eof() value. Here is a piece of code for understanding:

```
 // 2nd reading.
  ssFile.unsetf(std::ios::skipws); // consider whitespaces
  while( !ssFile.eof() && ssFile >> c ) {

   if(c != ' ' && c != '\n') { // until gets 1 char

    while( !ssFile.eof() && c != ' ' && c != '\n' ) {
     pattern += c;
     ssFile >> c;
    }

    if( pattern == "<frame>" || pattern == "next:" || pattern == "hit_a:" || pattern == "hit_d:" || pattern == "hit_j:" || pattern == "hit_Fa:" || pattern == "hit_Ua:" || pattern == "hit_Da:" || pattern == "hit_Uj:" || pattern == "hit_Dj:" || pattern == "hit_Fj:" || pattern == "hit_dja:") {


     do { // Search next first char.
      ssFile >> c;
     } while ( !ssFile.eof() && c == ' ' && c == '\n' );
```

In every looping I added the !ssFile.eof() in the conditions. There was my error.

So my problem IS solved, and was definitely not related to the title of my question, sorry.

If, by curiosity, someone happens to spot things that I do wrong, don't hesitate to tell me please :)

Comment: For the files for which it runs an endless loop, what is the value of chunk? Perhaps, you can print it out outside of if to get an idea for debugging...

Comment: Maybe blank lines at the end of these files?

Comment: I made other tests (see edits) and shared my outputs. It appears there is no endless loop, the program gets stuck at the last occurence waiting for I don't know what... frame 33 really is the last occurence in the file. On top of that an EOF is detected. So Im confused now. 
@hidrargyro some files have blank lines, some don't. Removing them or not doesn't alter the output at all :(

Comment: Last edit: program gets stuck at the last occurence for some time, then gets aborted due to a bad allocation. This only happens with these 5 files out of 100. My knowledge clearly meets its end here.
Any idea ?

Comment: @AlexandreToqué: I'm not 100 percent sure what is wrong, but I suspect `ssFile >> value;` is failing. Make sure the read is successful everytime, i.e. `if(!(ssFile >> value)) {std::cout << "Failed"!;}`.

Comment: @JesseGood: reporting: no operator failure met. Output remains the same :(

Comment: As a sanity check, put cout << ssFile.str().c_str() << endl; before while loop to print contents of the whole stringstream prior to looping through it.

Comment: Tanks for that advice. I debugged it line by line and finally solved my problem, which had nothing to do with loops actually. I explained in my last edit. Any comment is welcome :)